# How to sort xml data by Date in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, sorting, date

This application is extracting information from an RSS feed and I need to sort the articles by date. The xml data contains a 'Date' element which lists the date in ddmmyy format. My question: is there a sort function I can implement in jQuery to sort the information and display it in the correct date order? (Date order should be the first entry to display is the furthest date out,example: 01/20/14 then 01/07/2014 then 12/22/13 etc...
Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
            var id = this.id;
            if(id == 'radio-bio') { var categoryURL = '/BayAreaTech/wp-rss2.php?cat=15';}
            else if (id == 'radio-com'){ var categoryURL = '/BayAreaTech/wp-rss2.php?cat=13';}
            else if (id == 'radio-eleP'){ var categoryURL = '/BayAreaTech/wp-rss2.php?cat=9';}
            else if (id == 'radio-eleD'){ var categoryURL = '/BayAreaTech/wp-rss2.php?cat=10';}
            else if (id == 'radio-nano'){ var categoryURL = '/BayAreaTech/wp-rss2.php?cat=16';}
            else if (id == 'radio-opt'){ var categoryURL = '/BayAreaTech/wp-rss2.php?cat=12';}
            else if (id == 'radio-semi'){ var categoryURL = '/BayAreaTech/wp-rss2.php?cat=11';}
            else { var categoryURL = '/BayAreaTech/wp-rss2.php?cat=1';}

            $('#feedContainer').empty();
                        $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: categoryURL,
                        dataType: 'xml',
                        success: function (xml) {
                            $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
                                  var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                                  var date = $(this).find("Date").text();
                                  var region = date.substr(6);
                                        if (region.length < 3) { region = "ALL"; }  
                                  var description = $(this).find("description").text();
                                  var descriptdisplay = description.substr(0, description.indexOf(",")+6); //Parsed DATE from description
                                        if (descriptdisplay.length > 35) { descriptdisplay = "See event for details"; }
                                    //var locationdisplay = description.substr(description.indexOf(",")+6,4); //Parsed the location from description
                                  var category = $(this).find("category").text();
                                  var linkUrl = $(this).find("link").text();
                                  var displaytitle = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>" + title + "</a>"  
                                  $('#feedContainer').append('<h3>'+displaytitle+'</h3><p>'+"Event Date: "+descriptdisplay+'</p><p>'+"Location: "+region+'</p');

                            });
                        }
                    });

        });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would suggest you first parse the xml into an array of objects that can be sorted, prior to parsing into html

```
success: function (xml) {
    var data=[];
    $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
      var dateText= $(this).find("Date").text()

      var item={
           title: $(this).find("title").text(),
           dateText =dateText,
           date : new Date( dateText),
           /* other properties*/
        }  
        /* push object to array*/
        data.push( item);

    });

    /* sort data*/
    data.sort(function(a,b){
         return a.date > b.date;
    });

     /* now parse to html */    
      $.each(data, function(index, item){


      })
```

Comment: Thank you for the feed back! I will work on implementing this. I have one question though, am I parse to html in the $.each(data, function()?

Comment: example `title` will be `item.title` within the loop. Basically need the first loop to store eveything to object from xml, second loop will now pull the data from each  object to wrap in your html

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. I will let you know how this works. Again, Thank you very much for your time and response!

Comment: I tried implementing the code you provided, however I am still have trouble. Can you have a look at the updated code?

Comment: I don't see updated code...you tried to edit my answer and 3 reviwers rejected it...updates should be made in question. Go here..http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:1986619... add xml and your code and save. Will get it working there for you

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize I did that. I uploaded the current html doc I have as well as one of the rss feeds. I dont know how to reference the saved rss file in Plunker, so right now I just hae the url of the ajax call directed toward the website. Also, the 'date' element I am trying to sort by is in ddmmyy format. Also some of the 'date' elements have a bit of extra information, such as: ddmmyySVC.I think this or the date format may be causing the problem. Thank you VERY much for helping! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: date field doesn't make sense to me, just a 6 digit number, not sure how to parse it and it's throwing date object off...used the date you parsed from the text  http://plnkr.co/edit/aYF7fNovVZgANViwvXAo?p=preview

Comment: what if the format is changed to yyyymmdd, can I parse that? The reason I wasnt using the date parsed from the text is it is inconsistent. Sometimes there are webinars that have multiple dates and so fourth. The date parse from the text is for displaying information to the user.

Comment: are you creating the xml? If so any format that you can run through `new Date(dateInText)` will work...then modify code a bit if it's somehing like `TBD`

Comment: I am not but I can request that the date element be adjusted.

Comment: there you go..that would help

Comment: Ok, so it has been updated to yyyymmdd format. I just plugged in the variable text of that element and ran it with no luck: var newDate = $(this).find("Date").text(); then....var newDate = new Date(newDate); this didn't work, so I tried new Date(yyyy,mm,dd) and that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: have to parse that into format that new Date will handle like `'2013-11-12'` or have output changed in xml `Date(yyyy,mm,dd)` will work if not strings, need to be number

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work: var tDate = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
   var newDate = new Date(tDate);

Comment: it should...works fine in console...`console.log( new Date ('2013-11-12'))`

Comment: Ok so switch the '-' to '/' ?

Comment: Made the adjustment and ran it. No luck. http://plnkr.co/edit/3DV5AmslglLlkJcoV13N?p=catalogue

Comment: can't get xml cross domain...look in console...demo won't pull in the data...have to copy it to file like I did. Confusing have multiple ajax calls in demo, why I got rid of second one

Comment: Ah ok! I wont have issues with cross-domain on a live version. When I run it in dreamweaver, cross-domain isn't taken into account though and I'm still getting mixed results. Should I load a version onto a server and test it there?

Comment: Also, this project is for school and since you've been helping a ton it'd like to send you a e-giftcard. If not, no worries. Just letting you know that my group and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I ran it on the server and am getting this console log output: Array[60]
 indexA.html:94
Denying load of chrome-extension://ganlifbpkcplnldliibcbegplfmcfigp/scripts/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension. indexA.html:1

Comment: I think the issue may be the fact that 40 of the records have the new format, whereas the remaining 20 (60 total) have the old format. Is there a way to drop a for loop in so only say 20 records are run through the compare function?

Comment: So I've got everything set up now like your example. and the date is being input in a yyyymmdd format into the new Date(). However the results is "Invalid Date" when I run the application on a server. Any suggestions?

Comment: likely thrown by passing `TBD` into `new Date`. Test if value is `TBD` before putting it into date object, and don't run it through if it is

Comment: ran a console.log() on textDate before the new Date() creation. Everything is in the proper format yyyymmdd before it is passed.

Comment: Well, not exactly. Passing new Date(textDate); returns "invalid Date." Am I missing a certain plugin or something?

Comment: that's where you need to test if it's `tbd` and don't pass it in

Comment: Its not getting passed in because I am keeping the element count to 15 . The first 15 "Date" elements have the correct format of yyyymmdd. So that's why I'm confused.

Comment: can't help with what I can't see

Comment: It's been awhile but I wanted to let you know this format is correct! I really appreciate it, thanks charlietfl.