# Using JQuery to Sort XML data

Tags: jquery, html, xml

Quite frankly this seems like it should be an extremely simple thing to accomplish however everything I've come across just doesn't work (Probably because of my limited experience)

**The problem:**
I'm using JQuery to parse a string into xml whereby I'll then display the results into a scoreboard. The issue is that I want to parse this string into xml and sort the data with a specific heading.

**I must stress:** I have no control over the initial variable, I cannot edit it and I cannot use plugins. This is a university project so I'm quite limited to what I can actually change.

The XML Data to be parsed and sorted:

```
var xmlData = "<Scores>" +
                        "<Game><Player>Andy Symons</Player><Time>30</Time><Moves>4</Moves></Game>" +
                        "<Game><Player>Joe Bloggs</Player><Time>35</Time><Moves>4</Moves></Game>" +
                        "<Game><Player>Jane Bloggs</Player><Time>28</Time><Moves>6</Moves></Game>" +
                        "<Game><Player>Jane Bloggs</Player><Time>30</Time><Moves>8</Moves></Game>" +
                        "<Game><Player>Joe Bloggs</Player><Time>55</Time><Moves>6</Moves></Game>" +
                    "</Scores>";
```

If anybody has any ideas how I can parse this string, and order the contents (Preferably as flexibly as possible as I'll need to be able to order the results from any of the headers)

Sorry if this makes no sense, I'll edit as needs be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20025370/2979342

Answer (score 0):

XML strings can be treated as HTML nodes with a little fiddling, and then they can be queried with jQuery or with plain JavaScript. For instance, taking what you have, we can create a dom object from the XML and query it for game document fragments:

```
function getVal(game, field) { return game.querySelector(field).childNodes[0] }

var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlData, 'text/xml');
var games = dom.querySelectorAll('Game');

console.log(games);
console.log(getVal(games[0], 'Player'));
```

Items from the games collection can have fields queried with the getVal function, and you can do with them what you want. If you can get the data sent to you with JSON, or if you can link to a third party JavaScript library to turn XML to JavaScript objects, that would make this a little easier.